# VBA Macro error when saving a csv file on Mac

Tags: vba

I'm trying to use the VBA macro below to save individual sheets as csv files. It works perfectly on windows, but only intermittently on my mac. When it doesn't work, it presents "Run-time error'1004': Method 'Save as' of object '_Workbook' failed". If I change the FileFormat parameter to xlOpenXMLWorkbook, then it works flawlessly on Mac too.

Given that its intermittent on Mac when using the xlCSV format and works flawlessly on Windows, I think it's a bug with the Mac version of Excel. But I'm hoping someone can point to something in the code.

```
Sub Export_tables()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim WHID As String
    
    WHID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create").Range("C3")
    FolderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & WHID & " Sorter tables"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    MkDir FolderPath

    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If xWs.Name = "Source" Or xWs.Name = "Revision history" Or xWs.Name = "Create" Or xWs.Name = "ReceiveSorter1-Example" Or xWs.Name = "ShippingSorter1-Example" Then
        GoTo Skip
        End If
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & WHID & " " & xWs.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
Skip:
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Tables exported to " & FolderPath
    
End Sub
```